# SELECT Query - String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Query below gives the error above

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.DoSRF_001 ( 001 ,0 ,-1 ,0 ,'2014-01-01' )
```

Funny thing is, anything other than '2014-01-01' runs fine. Like '2015-01-01' or '2013-01-01'.

Function has hundreds of lines. But I thought it might have an easy solution.

Here are the parameters

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DoSRF_001] 
(  
     @FirmNo int = NULL  
    ,@DeptNo int = NULL  
    ,@SiteNo int = NULL  
    ,@UnitNo int = NULL  
    ,@PerdBeg datetime = NULL  
)
```

Comment: Can you at least show the parameter definitions for the function? I doubt it is them, if, as you say, substituting `3` or `5` for `4` makes it run fine, in which case we will need the function. Can you try creating a smaller function that has the same problems (e.g. try stripping out everything other than the final parameter, any queries that don't use it, etc), and then make sure that this smaller function also exhibits the error.

Comment: edit your function so before it does anything else, it returns out.  this will show if it is the calling parameters or how you use them within the function.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the "String or Binary data would be truncated" error is only producte when trying to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` data - I would check the places where you are actually updating a table and see what column values could have strings larger than the column width (e.g. if they're pulled from a different table).